# Как удалить процессы из памяти в Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Программа работает на **multiprocessing**, а именно на **ThreadPool**.
Цикл **while** запускает множество процессов с помощью **.apply_async()**.
Позже процессы завершаются методами: **.close()** и **.terminate()**. И на всякий случай удаляю переменную через **del()**.

Но я стал замечать, что программа берёт много **оперативки** через большое количество часов по сравнению с началом запуска программы.
Думаю в памяти остаются какие-то процессы и не знаю как решить проблему.

Comment: Надо не «думать», а открыть диспетчер задач и посмотреть, что где берёт оперативку. Действительно ли там будет множество процессов?

Comment: Нужно хоть какой-то код привести, так это гадание будет на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Я зашёл и там один процесс **python**. 
Чтобы проверить так ли это. Поставил программу на ночь и сделал запись нагрузки ОЗУ каждые пол минуты. И на утро моя программа стала занимать на 1ГБ больше оперативной памяти.